# How to upload a Video file to Twitter

Tags: android, video, twitter, twitter-fabric

There are already many questions like that but unfortunately they are not answered and outdated 
[Upload video to twitvid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927050/upload-video-to-twitvid)
[How to upload a video to twitter in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558338/how-to-upload-a-video-to-twitter-in-android-application)
[Best way to upload video on twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309906/best-way-to-upload-video-on-twitter)

I'm using Twitter4j to an upload image and it is working good but when I use same code to upload video , only the message tweeted and there is no video

```
StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(message);
statusUpdate.setMedia(files[0]);
Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
```

Also I don't know if [twitvid](http://www.twitvid.com/) still available because I tried to download it but it doesn't exist
Also what about Fabric Twitter Kit, is it supported to upload video ?? because I didn't find any thing on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can user TweetComposer for sharing to Twitter.

```
TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(mContext)
                        .text(status)
                        .image(videoUri);

                builder.show();
```

Careful while sharing Uri in 24 n above , Uri should be

```
 content://com.sample.myproject.provider/my_images/Image430.jpg
```

in this format.

Comment: how we can upload without twiiter composer ! any idea?